# How to measure input levels test on Kubuntu?

Tags: sound, software-recommendation, kubuntu, microphone

I noticed that in Ubuntu the sound/volume tool gives the chance to change the input volume/level while you speak through the microphone and there is a bar giving you the measure for the volume of your voice.

In Kubuntu, however, I have been unable to find it nor information anywhere about such a thing.

How can I obtain a graph with the input level while adjusting the volume of the input in Kubuntu 14.04.1 LTS Trusty Tahr?

Answer (score 0):

you can install    pavucontrol . It's a pretty nice sound system.

```
 sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

[image]